# TinyMCE - load whole html content without altering meta head JavaScript tags

Tags: tinymce

When I load file.html to TinyMCE, just content in body tag is available. I would like to be able to edit whole html site content with TinyMCE without striping html, head, meta, script tags, or other tags. How is this possible please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin called `fullpage` that will allow you to do what you want:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/fullpage/